# Why strtok_r() only accepts character array but not character pointer

Tags: c++

**When I tried to compile the below code it compiles fine.**

```
char str[] = "I am Lokesh Kumar. But I liked to be called The Loki";
char *token;
char *p = str;
while (token = strtok_r(p, " ", &p)) {
    cout << token << endl;
}
```

**But a error** 
"*[Error] cannot convert 'char (*)[53]' to 'char**' for argument '3' to 'char* strtok_r(char*, const char*, char**)*"
 **popped out for below code**

```
char str[] = "I am Lokesh Kumar. But I liked to be called The Loki";
char *token;
char *p = str;
while (token = strtok_r(str, " ", &str)) {
    cout << token << endl;
}
```

`str` and `p` both holds the address of first character element, then why this error

Comment: Why do you do `char *p=str;`?

Comment: @alk, because `strtok_r` requires the address of a pointer.  Each call to `strtok_r` updates this pointer to point to the new token.  The line you ask about initializes this pointer.

Comment: @MartinBonner: "*The line you ask about initializes this pointer.*" I know.  But why?

Comment: @alk because "`strtok_r` requires the address of a pointer"

Comment: @MartinBonner: To pass the address of a pointer `p` you do not need to initialise the pointer `p`.

Comment: @alk - oh I see.  `p` doesn't need to be initialized.

Comment: If you want to write C code, use a C, not a C++ compiler. They are diggerent languages.

Comment: If there is no `*` in the parentheses with the wrong type, the message does not make sense. And you cannot pass an array to a function..

Answer (score 4):

`strtok_r` takes the address of a `char` pointer as its third argument. It will update this pointer to point past the matched token (or some other internal use). `str` is not a pointer, it is an array of `char`, you cannot pass its address to `strtok_r` because the address of an array is not the same thing as the address of a pointer.

The confusion come from the automatic conversion of array objects to pointers to their first elements that occurs when an array is used in most expression contexts, such as `p = str`.

Arrays and pointers are very different things, just like families and individual names. A family (*array*) is a collection of people (*characters*), a full name (*pointer*) points to an individual. A pointer to pointer to character is similar to a piece of paper on which you can write the name of a individual person (*character* in the sense of a person ;).

Not also these points:

- `p` does not need to be initialized before passing its address to `strtok_r` with a non `NULL` first argument;
- `p` should not be passed to `strtok_r` as the first argument in subsequent calls,
- It is considered poor coding style to use an assignment expression as a test expression in a conditional statement, you should parenthesize the assignment and compare the value to `NULL` explicity.

Here is a corrected version:

```
char str[] = "I am Lokesh Kumar. But I liked to be called The Loki";
char *token;
char *arg = str;
char *p;

while ((token = strtok_r(arg, " ", &p)) != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", token);  // using printf since you tagged the question as C
    arg = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`str` is an array, `p` is a pointer. It's not true that

> str and p both holds the address of first character element

What is true is that `str` is convertable to the address of the first character. But you are doing this `&str` so you get the address of the array, not the address of the first character.

Since `strtok_r` requires a modifiable pointer to a character there's no way to get that other than to declare a pointer variable. Unless you decide to pass `nullptr` to the third parameter of course.

Comment: It is worth going on to point out that strtok wants to update the pointer which is pointed to by its third argument, and `&str` gives the address of the array, not the address of a modifiable pointer.

Comment: `&str[0]` would give the address of the first character

Comment: @MartinCook - but `&p` gives the address of a pointer holding the address of the first character.  You'd have to type `&&str[0]` to get that - except that you can't take the address of an expression like `&str[0]` (technically, you can't take the address of an rvalue, but I don't suppose the OP knows what an rvalue is).

Comment: @MartinBonner yes, absolutely, don't mean to imply that `&str[0]` is the same as `&p`, or that `&str[0]` would work in the call to `strtok_r`... I just added the comment for interest's sake, because the answer mentioned "address of the first character"

Answer (score 1):

`p` has type `char*` so `&p` has type `char**`, as required.

`str` has type `char ()[53]`, so `&str` has type `char (*)[53]`.

The array *decays* to a pointer to the first element in many contexts, but it's not the same thing.

Anyway, you know the 3rd parameter to `strtok_r` can be `NULL` to start? It's only *output* for the first call.

Comment: Sometimes meaning of `char ()[53]` or  `char(*)[53]` is not self-explanatory. What are their meanings? Would you mind explaining?

Comment: @snr `char ()[53]` means "an array of 53 characters".  (The `()` marks where the name of the array would go in a declaration and can be omitted.)  `char (*)[53]` means "a pointer to an array of 53 characters" (You *could* declare such a beast as `char (*ptr)[53]` - but please don't.  Much better to use `typedef char char53array[53];` which declares a typedef for an array of 53 characters, and then `char53array* ptr;` - which declares a pointer to such a beast.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic example usage of [strtok_r](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok_r).  Though you already got detailed information about char array and pointer difference from @john answer.

Just for the simplicity sake, I am adding this example. I don't know why you want the pointer to point str.

You can delimit the string into token in below simple way.

There are two ways to solve the issue.

```
char str[] = "I am Lokesh Kumar. But I liked to be called The Loki";
cahr *p;
char *token = strtok_r(str, " ", &p);
```